# Is there a way in Ember to get component/view/route based on div id like ember8013?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way in Ember to get component/view/route based on div id like ember8013?
This is just for debugging.

Comment: using the ember inspector is not an option?

Comment: I have an old version of Ember (1.10) and the inspector is not working.

Comment: this.element.id ?

Comment: I am trying to do this in debugger and so, can't use this.element.id

Comment: can you modify the code? you could use `didInsertElement` to build a map of id->component on `window`.